# How to capture run/debug logs in a file in WebStorm

Tags: npm, webstorm

I am having an npm run/debug configuration in WebStorm for which I want to save the logs to a file. I could not find any logs tab to provide the file path and neither I can see "Modify options" to provide the configuration to save console output in a file.

[image]

Comment: Add `--loglevel verbose` to the Arguments field, isn't it?

Comment: but if we have save them to a file. Do you know of argument which we can pass to provide the file name/path for saving the logs

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for [WEB-49951](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49951) to be notified on any progress with this feature